# Time of flying from Toronto to Philippines

Tags: safety, boeing-777

Please I would 
Like  to know how many hours I will be flying
Across the ocean . I will be flying on an aircraft 773 boing 777.

Comment: This looks like it would be better suited for Travel.SE.

Comment: If you know what you are flying on, then I assume you have your tickets. Every airline I've booked through gives some kind of estimate of the total flight time along with arrival and departure times.

Comment: @RonBeyer True, but I understand that the OP is interested in the time spent _over the ocean_, not the total flight time.

Answer (score 3):

A direct flight from Toronto to Manila is about 16 hours. It is classified as a "Polar" flight and very little of it would be over the open ocean.

Depending on the weather and upper wind conditions, you would be initially flying either North East, or North West, from Toronto.

Most of the flight will be over land, with some of it over the frozen Arctic Ocean or Sea of Okhotsk near Russia.

[FlightRadar24 PR119/PAL119](https://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/pr119#)

[image]
[image]